Remove embedded OLE object from ms-ppt file
I want to remove embedded OLE object from PPT(2003, HSLF) file format. According to ppt documentation i can list ole objects from shapes and use removeShape from HSLF.
List<HSLFSlide> slides = ppt.getSlides();
for (HSLFSlide sl : slides) {
    for (HSLFShape shape : slide.getShapes()) {
        if (shape instanceof HSLFObjectShape) {
            HSLFObjectShape ole = (HSLFObjectShape) shape;
            // remove the shape
                boolean ok = slide.removeShape(shape);
                if (ok) {
                    // the shape was removed. Do something.
                }
        }
    }
}

HSLFObjectData[] ole = ppt.getEmbeddedObjects() // not null

But it doesn't work for all files. When i list the shapes of my ppt file (malicious sample) there is no HSLFObjectShape in it. But when i list embedded objects i can find it but can't remove it. I understand in PPT there is records and need to remove it accurately. As i understand there is addEmbed function to add embedded object but no direct function to remove it. How can i do this?
PS: I can setData of OLE object but open new ppt with MS Office it still asks to 'enable macro content', so i need to remove it completely
